# Print file name in front of grep matched pattern output lines

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I want to print line content of a matched pattern from a input file to a output file. I am using:

```
    grep -hnr "pattern" ./input.txt > output.txt
```

Output.txt file is like:

```
this line has the word pattern in it
```

But I want to print name of the input file in the same line in output file. For example,  I want the output file to be like:

```
input this line has the word pattern in it
```

If the pattern matches multiple times in input file, I want to print filenames multiple times. For example:

```
input this line has the word pattern in it 
input this line also has same pattern
```

and finally, I want to do this in a directory with many input files (*.txt format) and generate one output.txt files with all results.

Comment: Just do `grep -hnr pattern ./*.txt` . If you list multiple input files, grep by default will print the name of the file that matches.

Comment: All UNIX tools have manual pages. `man grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use :

```
 grep -H "pattern" ./input.txt > output.txt
```

From `man grep` :

> -H, --with-filename
>         Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search.
>
> -h, --no-filename
>         Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.